# Checking values inside an Array List

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm doing a project on insertion sort and I whipped up this project, having no prior experience on Array Lists I'm getting an error regarding checking the values inside a specific index.

```
int unsorted[] = {10, 4, 52, 5, 7};
    ArrayList sorted = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    sorted.add(unsorted[0]);

    for (int i=1; i <= unsorted.length; i++){
        int x=0;
        while (unsorted[i] > sorted(x)){
            x++;
            if (unsorted[i]<= sorted(x)){
                sorted.set(x,unsorted[i]);
            if (x > sorted.size()){
                sorted.add(unsorted[i]);
```

I'm getting errors on both `sorted(x)` in the example can anyone tell me how to check a value inside an Array List at a specific index?

Comment: The first place you should be looking is in the official `ArrayList` documentation. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: "I'm getting an error" what error????

Comment: I think `unsorted[1]` is a typo.

Comment: What does the error message say? Also, you are starting with the index `1`, not `0`. Is this correct?

Comment: Maybe you could place all of your code.

Comment: @shmosel thanks man didn't notice that

Comment: @redxef yeah I placed index 0 in beforehand so I would have something to compare to

Comment: @JonasAnon there ya go!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank your for all your suggestions! The majority of you suggested I use .get but I was getting an error when using it. It turned out I didn't define the type the ArrayList would hold so I couldn't use .get. I fixed this by adding `ArrayList<Integer> sorted = new ArrayList<Integer>();`
and
`if (unsorted[i]<= sorted.get(x)){`

Answer (score 1):

Getting the element of a `List` is done via the `get()` method, you can look this up in the official Java Doc, which @BilltheLizard already linked to:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Setting an element is done using the `set()` method, which you have already done.

Basically an object always has methods for manipulating it.

Comment: thanks, I've tried and got an error but maybe I wasn't doing it right I'll check out the link

Answer (score 1):

If you Want to sort by insertion sort you can try this code.

```
int unsorted[]={1,5,2,7,3};
    for (int i = 1; i < unsorted.length; i++) {
        int key=unsorted[i];
        int j=i-1;
        while((j > -1) && ( unsorted [j] > key )){
            unsorted [j+1] = unsorted [j];
            j--;
        }
        unsorted[j+1]=key;

    }

    for (int x = 0; x < unsorted.length; x++) {
        System.out.print(unsorted[x] + ", ");
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `sorted.get(index)`

Comment: i tried that but it only lead to a bigger error @Janus Varmarken

Comment: `unsorted` is an array. Maybe you mean `sorted.get(x)`?

Comment: True, it LOOKS like it, but it's not obvious as the definition of unsorted is not there. OP could just as well be coming from a language that has subscript syntax, e.g. swift. Don't really get why this was downvoted...

Comment: @shmosel that's what I assumed he meant

Comment: The fact that there's `unsorted.length`, and the contrast between `unsorted[i]` and `sorted(x)` makes it clear that the former is an array and the latter is a syntax mistake. But if you weren't sure, you shouldn't have posted.

Comment: @shmosel why not I assumed questions you are unsure about is why there is a forum where you can ask people for advice

Comment: As sorted(x) is gibberish, how can we assume he got unsorted right?

Comment: @SpencerHopkins This isn't a forum, it's a question & answer site that follows a specific format. Both the question and answer should be clear and stand on their own (neither do). If there's some confusion, that should be cleared up in the comments first.

Comment: @Janus Varmarken I'm well versed in proper syntax for arrays but not arraylists as I said in my initial question. unsorted is fine I can assure you

Comment: @JanusVarmarken Like I said, it seemed pretty clear to me. But all you've done is made an even less plausible assumption and answered that instead. How is that better?

Comment: @shmosel any suggestions on how I can make it more clear, maybe post the rest of the code or something because the question itself seems pretty clear but maybe the presentation of the implementation was confusing

Comment: @SpencerHopkins Ideally, you should post a [mcve] so we can see the full context. At the very least, we'd need to see the variable declarations and the specific error message. But the truth is the question should never have been posted, because this could have all been avoided by reading the documentation or any basic Java tutorial.

Comment: @shmosel The question is essentially "can anyone tell me how to check a value inside an Array List at a specific index?". Whether I answer that by sorted.get(x), unsorted.get(x) or someOtherVariableName.get(x) doesn't really make much of a difference imho.

Comment: @shmosel Agree.

Comment: @shmosel I was checking the index and it didn't make any sense to me so I decided to come here. I understand it's simplistic but that doesn't mean it is of less value to the website

Answer (score 0):

Compilations errors should be avoided by using the right method to get an item from  a `List` (and an ArrayList by consequence): [`get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-).

Arrays and `ArrayList` both have indexes starting from 0, not 1.
You should get an error when the index is equal to the length of your array or `ArrayList`so `unsorted[unsorted.length]` should trigger an error.

IMHO your first loop should be

```
for (int i=1; i < unsorted.length; i++){
```

Note also that you could use the [`add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-int-E-) method instead of the `set` in order to insert items.

Comment: unsorted is an array, sorted is an array list

Comment: and I already added unsorted 0 into the array list before hand

Comment: oops sorry for my remark, I answered too fast...but I think you should encounter the index issue.

Comment: I didn't put it in but I made that precaution already, but thanks for the input

Comment: no, because then it would check and add a value that is already in the array if you use that loop since I already added unsorted[0] into the sorted array list so starting at 1 is how it would be done

Comment: @SpencerHopkins ok but you have to stop before `unsorted.length`

Comment: wouldn't that just not check the final int in the array?

Comment: @SpencerHopkins No the last index is at `length - 1` because the first index is 0!